# Xamarin Visual Studio Error MSB4064 and MSB4063

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I get the error after creating a new blank Xamarin project. As soon as the project is generated I get the errors:

> Warning    IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   Droid2      1   Active
>
> Warning        The "ChecksumAlgorithm" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.   Droid2
>
> Warning        The "Csc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.  Droid2

I've tried several times uninstalling Xamarin and reinstalling to no avail.

The build log file is too big to add in its entirety so I just added the last bit. (30000 char limit)

```
    Target "_ExtractLibraryProjectImports" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Using "ReadLibraryProjectImportsCache" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
      Task "ReadLibraryProjectImportsCache"
        Task ReadLibraryProjectImportsCache
          CacheFile: obj\Debug\libraryprojectimports.cache
          Jars: 
          ResolvedAssetDirectories: 
          ResolvedResourceDirectories: 
          ResolvedEnvironmentFiles: 
          ResolvedResourceDirectoryStamps: 
      Done executing task "ReadLibraryProjectImportsCache".
    Done building target "_ExtractLibraryProjectImports" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_CrunchLibraryProjectImports" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(AndroidExplicitCrunch)' == 'True' And '$(AndroidApplication)' != '' And $(AndroidApplication)) was evaluated as ( 'False' == 'True' And 'true' != '' And true).
    Target "_AddMultiDexDependencyJars" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(AndroidEnableMultiDex)' == 'True') was evaluated as ('False' == 'True').
    Done building target "_AddMultiDexDependencyJars" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
      Input files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll;D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\Droid2.csproj;obj\Debug\build.props
      Output files: obj\Debug\libraryimports.cache
    Done building target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_GetLibraryImports" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Using "ReadImportedLibrariesCache" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
      Task "ReadImportedLibrariesCache"
        Task ReadImportedLibrariesCache
          CacheFile: obj\Debug\libraryimports.cache
          NativeLibraries: 
          Jars: 
          ManifestDocuments: 
      Done executing task "ReadImportedLibrariesCache".
      Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ExtractedNativeLibraryImports)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
    Done building target "_GetLibraryImports" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "GetNativeProjectLibraries" skipped, due to false condition; ($(NativeAndroidInstalled)) was evaluated as (false).
    Target "_GetLibraryImports" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    Target "_CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Using "CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
      Task "CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries"
          JavaSourceFiles:
          JavaLibraries:
          LibraryProjectJars:
      Done executing task "CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries".
    Done building target "_CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_ValidateResourceCache" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Using "ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
      Task "ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache"
        Task ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache
          CacheFile: obj\Debug\resourcepaths.cache
          AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths: 
          AdditionalJavaLibraryReferences: 
          AdditionalNativeLibraryReferences: 
          IsValid: True
      Done executing task "ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache".
      Task "Delete" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_IsResourceCacheValid)' == 'False' ) was evaluated as ( 'True' == 'False' ).
    Done building target "_ValidateResourceCache" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_SetupDesignTimeBuildForIntellisense" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
    Done building target "_SetupDesignTimeBuildForIntellisense" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Skipping target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
      Input files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll
      Output files: obj\Debug\resourcepaths.cache
    Done building target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Task "ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache"
        Task ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache
          CacheFile: obj\Debug\resourcepaths.cache
          AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths: 
          AdditionalJavaLibraryReferences: 
          AdditionalNativeLibraryReferences: 
          IsValid: True
      Done executing task "ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache".
      Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; (Exists ('%(_AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths.Identity)\AndroidManifest.xml')) was evaluated as (Exists ('\AndroidManifest.xml')).
    Done building target "_GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_CalculateAdditionalResourceCacheDirectories" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Using "CalculateAdditionalResourceCacheDirectories" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
      Task "CalculateAdditionalResourceCacheDirectories"
        CalculateAdditionalResourceCacheDirectories Task
          AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths:
          CacheDirectory: obj\Debug\resourcecache
      Done executing task "CalculateAdditionalResourceCacheDirectories".
    Done building target "_CalculateAdditionalResourceCacheDirectories" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    Target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because it has no outputs.
      Though the target has declared its outputs, the output specification only references empty properties and/or empty item lists.
    Done building target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    Target "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
      Input files: Resources\layout\Main.axml;Resources\values\Strings.xml;Resources\drawable\Icon.png;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets;D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\Droid2.csproj;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Xaml.targets;obj\Debug\build.props
      Output files: D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml;D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml;D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\obj\Debug\res\drawable\icon.png
    Done building target "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
      Input files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll;D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml;D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml;D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\obj\Debug\res\drawable\icon.png;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets;D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\Droid2.csproj;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Xaml.targets
      Output files: obj\Debug\R.cs.flag
    Done building target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_AddLibraryProjectsEmbeddedResourceToProject" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
      Using "CreateManagedLibraryResourceArchive" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
      Task "CreateManagedLibraryResourceArchive"
      Done executing task "CreateManagedLibraryResourceArchive".
      Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; (Exists ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)__AndroidLibraryProjects__.zip')) was evaluated as (Exists ('obj\Debug\__AndroidLibraryProjects__.zip')).
    Done building target "_AddLibraryProjectsEmbeddedResourceToProject" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_GenerateJavaDesignerForComponent" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(_AdditonalAndroidResourceCachePaths)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
    Target "UpdateAndroidResources" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets":
    Done building target "UpdateAndroidResources" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    Target "ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.PCLSupport.targets":
      Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(ReferencePath.ResolvedFrom)' == 'ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades') was evaluated as ('{TargetFrameworkDirectory}' == 'ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades').
      Task "Message"
Done executing task "Message".
    Done building target "ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "ResolveReferences" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
    Done building target "ResolveReferences" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "ResolveKeySource" skipped, due to false condition; ($(SignManifests) == 'true' or $(SignAssembly) == 'true') was evaluated as ( == 'true' or  == 'true').
    Target "ResolveComReferences" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(COMReference)'!='' or '@(COMFileReference)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='' or ''!='').
    Target "ResolveNativeReferences" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(NativeReference)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
    Target "_SetExternalWin32ManifestProperties" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(GenerateClickOnceManifests)'=='true' or '@(NativeReference)'!='' or '@(ResolvedIsolatedComModules)'!='') was evaluated as (''=='true' or ''!='' or ''!='').
    Target "_SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
      Using "GetFrameworkPath" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
      Task "GetFrameworkPath"
      Done executing task "GetFrameworkPath".
    Done building target "_SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "SetWin32ManifestProperties" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
    Done building target "SetWin32ManifestProperties" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_GenerateCompileInputs" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
      Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ManifestResourceWithNoCulture)'!='' and '%(ManifestResourceWithNoCulture.EmittedForCompatibilityOnly)'=='') was evaluated as (''!='' and ''=='').
      Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ManifestNonResxWithNoCultureOnDisk)'!='' and '%(ManifestNonResxWithNoCultureOnDisk.EmittedForCompatibilityOnly)'=='') was evaluated as (''!='' and ''=='').
    Done building target "_GenerateCompileInputs" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "PrepareForBuild" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    Target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    Target "_SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets":
    Done building target "_SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
      Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
      Input files: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.targets
      Output files: C:\Users\Ids\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs
    Done building target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "GenerateAdditionalSources" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(AssemblyAttributes)' != '' and '$(GenerateAdditionalSources)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' != '' and '' == 'true').
    Target "BeforeCompile" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
    Done building target "BeforeCompile" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "_TimeStampBeforeCompile" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(RunPostBuildEvent)'=='OnOutputUpdated' or ('$(RegisterForComInterop)'=='true' and '$(OutputType)'=='library')) was evaluated as (''=='OnOutputUpdated' or (''=='true' and 'Library'=='library')).
    Target "GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFile" in file "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WorkflowBuildExtensions.targets":
      Task "WriteLinesToFile" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFilePathForEditing)')) was evaluated as (!Exists('obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs')).
      Task "WriteLinesToFile" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFilePathForValidation)')) was evaluated as (!Exists('obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs')).
      Task "WriteLinesToFile" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFilePathForTypeInfer)')) was evaluated as (!Exists('obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs')).
    Done building target "GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFile" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "DesignTimeXamlMarkupCompilation" in file "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets":
      Task "MakeDir" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(XamlAppDef)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
      Task "CallTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BuildingProject)' != 'true' and '@(XamlAppDef)' != '') was evaluated as ('false' != 'true' and '' != '').
    Done building target "DesignTimeXamlMarkupCompilation" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "CleanInProcessXamlGeneratedFiles" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(XamlAppDef)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
    Target "_ComputeNonExistentFileProperty" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
    Done building target "_ComputeNonExistentFileProperty" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets":
      Using "ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
      Task "ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet"
      Done executing task "ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet".
    Done building target "ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "PreXsdCodeGen" in file "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.ServiceModel.targets":
      Using "CallTarget" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
      Task "CallTarget"
        Target "CleanXsdCodeGen" in file "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.ServiceModel.targets":
          Using "Delete" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
          Task "Delete"
          Done executing task "Delete".
        Done building target "CleanXsdCodeGen" in project "Droid2.csproj".
      Done executing task "CallTarget".
    Done building target "PreXsdCodeGen" in project "Droid2.csproj".
    Target "XsdCodeGen" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(XsdCodeGenPreCondition)' == 'True' ) was evaluated as ( 'False' == 'True' ).
    Target "CoreCompile" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets":
      Building target "CoreCompile" completely.
      Output file "obj\Debug\Droid2.dll" does not exist.
      Using "Csc" task from assembly "C:\Users\Ids\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\enunflvr.wib\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll".
      Task "Csc"
        C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(76,11): error MSB4064: The "ChecksumAlgorithm" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
        C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(67,5): error MSB4063: The "Csc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters. 
      Done executing task "Csc" -- FAILED.
    Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "Droid2.csproj" -- FAILED.
    
    Done building project "Droid2.csproj" -- FAILED.
    
    Project Performance Summary:
          125 ms  D:\Play App\Droid2\Droid2\Droid2.csproj    1 calls
    
    Target Performance Summary:
            0 ms  _AddMultiDexDependencyJars                 1 calls
            0 ms  ResolveSDKReferences                       1 calls
            0 ms  _SetupDesignTimeBuildForIntellisense       1 calls
            0 ms  GetInstalledSDKLocations                   1 calls
            0 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  1 calls
            0 ms  _ValidateAndroidPackageProperties          1 calls
            0 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
            0 ms  ResolveReferences                          1 calls
            0 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 calls
            0 ms  _GenerateCompileInputs                     1 calls
            0 ms  _BuildAdditionalResourcesCache             1 calls
            0 ms  _ResolveLibraryProjectImports              1 calls
            0 ms  _BuildSdkCache                             1 calls
            0 ms  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute    1 calls
            0 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   1 calls
            0 ms  GetFrameworkPaths                          1 calls
            0 ms  _CalculateAdditionalResourceCacheDirectories   1 calls
            0 ms  AfterResolveReferences                     1 calls
            0 ms  _SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties        1 calls
            0 ms  _CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries               1 calls
            0 ms  _GetLibraryImports                         1 calls
            0 ms  _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir                  1 calls
            0 ms  _ResolveMonoAndroidFramework               1 calls
            0 ms  _SeparateAppExtensionReferences            1 calls
            0 ms  _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence     1 calls
            0 ms  _BuildLibraryImportsCache                  1 calls
            0 ms  _ComputeNonExistentFileProperty            1 calls
            0 ms  _GenerateAndroidResourceDir                1 calls
            0 ms  SetWin32ManifestProperties                 1 calls
            0 ms  BeforeResolveReferences                    1 calls
            0 ms  _GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                 1 calls
            0 ms  CleanXsdCodeGen                            1 calls
            0 ms  _UpdateAndroidResgen                       1 calls
            0 ms  ModifyUnitTestPlatformVersion              1 calls
            0 ms  _ComputeAndroidResourcePaths               1 calls
            0 ms  _SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute        1 calls
            0 ms  _AddLibraryProjectsEmbeddedResourceToProject   1 calls
            0 ms  UpdateAndroidResources                     1 calls
            0 ms  ExpandSDKReferences                        1 calls
            0 ms  BeforeCompile                              1 calls
            0 ms  PrepareForBuild                            1 calls
            0 ms  PreXsdCodeGen                              1 calls
            0 ms  _ExtractLibraryProjectImports              1 calls
            0 ms  ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet                 1 calls
            0 ms  _ComputeAndroidAssetsPaths                 1 calls
            0 ms  DesignTimeXamlMarkupCompilation            1 calls
            0 ms  _CheckForDeletedResourceFile               1 calls
            0 ms  _CreateAdditionalResourceCache             1 calls
            0 ms  _GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies      1 calls
            0 ms  GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFile        1 calls
            0 ms  UpdateAndroidAssets                        1 calls
           16 ms  _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks                    1 calls
           16 ms  ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades          1 calls
           16 ms  _ValidateResourceCache                     1 calls
           16 ms  CoreCompile                                1 calls
           31 ms  _SetLatestTargetFrameworkVersion           1 calls
           31 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                  1 calls
    
    Task Performance Summary:
            0 ms  CreateItem                                 1 calls
            0 ms  CallTarget                                 1 calls
            0 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          1 calls
            0 ms  GetAndroidPackageName                      1 calls
            0 ms  CreateProperty                            39 calls
            0 ms  ReadImportedLibrariesCache                 1 calls
            0 ms  Csc                                        1 calls
            0 ms  CreateManagedLibraryResourceArchive        1 calls
            0 ms  CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries                1 calls
            0 ms  ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet                 1 calls
            0 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  2 calls
            0 ms  GetAppSettingsDirectory                    1 calls
            0 ms  Message                                   13 calls
            0 ms  Delete                                     1 calls
            0 ms  MakeDir                                    2 calls
            0 ms  ReadLibraryProjectImportsCache             1 calls
            0 ms  GetFrameworkPath                           1 calls
            0 ms  ReadResolvedSdksCache                      1 calls
            0 ms  AndroidComputeResPaths                     2 calls
            0 ms  GetJavaPlatformJar                         1 calls
            0 ms  CalculateAdditionalResourceCacheDirectories   1 calls
            0 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 calls
           16 ms  GetAndroidDefineConstants                  1 calls
           16 ms  ReadAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblyCache   2 calls
           31 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   1 calls
    
    Build FAILED.
    
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(76,11): error MSB4064: The "ChecksumAlgorithm" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(67,5): error MSB4063: The "Csc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters. 
        0 Warning(s)
        2 Error(s)
    
    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.14
```

Answer (score 2):

#### If it happens after a `Xamarin.Forms` NuGet package update:

1. Clean NuGet cache (will clean *all* cached NuGets in the present directory and below)

   ```
   rm -rf `find . -name "packages"` # exhaustive and efficient
   nuget locals all -clear          # also clear cache
   ```
2. Close Solution. Quit Visual Studio for good measures and start over.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after Update 3 and my proj file had the correct order. A co-worker helped me troubleshoot. It turned out I had the Roslyn Insiders extension installed and it was high-jacking the compiler. Once I removed that extension, everything worked fine again.

[image]

Comment: Good to know. I managed to fix the problem by doing a complete re-install. I don't remember if I had that installed, but I'll not install these until these are a release version (if at all).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, there is a workaround posted here - https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/issues/1789

Comment: I've already looked at this. The project file is already in the correct order.

Comment: The only way I found to fix the problem was to completely uninstall Visual Studio 2015 and re-install. A repair install didn't fix it.